# Manually installing NPM packages

Tags: node.js, installation, express

I used the node windows installer v0.8.3 to install nodejs.
When I try to install express like this:

```
npm install express
```

It's not working. I think that is because my company is using a proxy, so I downloaded express from github https://github.com/visionmedia/express, but I don't know how to install.

I unzip the file and put them in F/express/. Please help me? I'm on Windows

When I try to install from F:/express/ using the following commands

```
cd F:/express
npm install ./express
```

or

```
npm install .
```

I get the following error:

```
error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at errnoException (net.js:776:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:767:19)
```

And when when I try to do

```
npm install F:/express
```

It shows

```
express@3.0.0beta7 prepublish F:/express/
npm prune
```

followed by lots of http get messages and then the same error

Comment: Are the http get messages for https://registry.npmjs.org/express or for different URLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would probably be most convenient long-term to configure NPM to use the aforementioned proxy through one of the following methods (In the following, replace $PROXY with your proxy in the form $PROTOCOL://$DOMAIN:$PORT (e.g. http://proxy.server:80))

A. Set the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy to $PROXY

B.

```
npm set proxy $PROXY
npm set https-proxy $PROXY
```

Comment: This does not work with an authenticating proxy. NPM is not smart enough to prompt you for a username/password to get through the proxy, or to handle proxy URLs of the form http://user:pass@proxy.company.com:1234.

Comment: @Maxy-B According to the comments at http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy, `http://login:pass@host:port` should work.

Answer (score 7):

express itself has a lot of dependencies which I believe npm also tries to retrieve if you issue `npm install`. I think you should just configure proxy properly => http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy?

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble getting packages because of a proxy or other internet connection problem then set up the project on another machine. Then copy the project over to your target. It will have all the files that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install .\express` (assuming the express folder is in the current folder).

The problem is that `express` in `npm install express` is parsed as a package name, while `.\express` in `npm install .\express` is parsed as a folder name.

Comment: do i need to specify the path like npm install .\F:\express

Comment: @chenliang What about (npm install F:\express)?

Comment: i tried npm install F:/express/ it shows alot of http get message and then the error : connect ETIMEDOUT at errnoException (net.js:776:11) at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:767:19)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to run `npm install .` from within your `F:/express/` folder (or `npm install -g .` for a global install).

It looks like you downloaded beta version (3.0.0beta7).  Try installing the latest stable version (2.5.11):

```
npm install https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tarball/2.5.11
```

Comment: i tried these npm install ./express; npm install .\express;npm install -g ./express none of is working

Comment: did you try `npm install .` (without the `/express`)?

Comment: i tried npm install . it shows alot of http get message and then the error : connect ETIMEDOUT at errnoException (net.js:776:11) at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:767:19)

Comment: @chenliang What URL is it trying to get?

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to include this error that you are getting? (Then others are more likely to see it.)

Comment: Also, what versions of npm and node are you using?

Comment: It's possible that an express dependency is not compatible with your version of node.

Comment: It looks like you are not the only person having this problem: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2609