# Durandal.js .NET VS2012 How to use Weyland in build process

Tags: build-process, durandal

I'm using the VSIX Durandal template (version 2.0).  The previous version (1.2) had an optimizer.exe which could be run as part of the build process.  I think Weyland has replaced this but I'm not sure how I can get this running as a build step in release mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release (
  cd "$(ProjectDir)"
  attrib -R App\main-built.js
  weyland build
)
```

I like to clear the read-only flag just in case main-built.js is put in source control, but you may not need that line.

Note: If the build fails (or you don't have node and weyland installed), then refer to the following page for more info: https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/254

Update:

To setup npm to use an authenticated proxy, try these commands in an elevated command prompt (last 2 may not be necessary, but are useful for other tools):

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080 
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080
setx http_proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080 /M
setx https_proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080 /M
```

Then restart Visual Studio (or reboot).  I think some might need to use https in the urls.  If username or password contains @, then surround with quotes like this: http://"username:p@assword"@proxy:8080

Comment: I'll mark this as correct as I've read the link in your answer and looked at other links which also suggest similar things. I can't actually test this though because, although I have node.js, I can't seem to install Weyland (npm install -g weyland) as I am behind a corporate proxy. i've tried the suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605621/manually-installing-npm-packages but that doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I'm also behind a corporate proxy, and it is one that uses authentication, so I did all of the following (not sure which one worked):
  
  npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080
  npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:8080
  set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080
  set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080

Comment: When I do this, I get the error: weyland is not recognized as an internal or external command'.  If i point directly to weyland, i get 'node is not recognized as an internal or external command'.   Any idea why environment paths aren't working in post-build?

Comment: In case anyone else comes accross this, the issue was that VS and/or MS Build seems to cache environment variables.  A reboot fixed the issue.

Comment: for those interested, there's a link here describing how to use node behind a corporate firewall. however, this still didn't work for me. http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

Comment: @bigerock See updates in my answer.  Be sure to include username and password if needed, try rebooting, and try https if necessary.

Comment: thanks @YipYip, my network admin temporarily disabled the corporate firewall for me instead - which worked, of course. once it's back on, i'll retry your suggestions. appreciated.