# Npm is definitely not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Every time I try to do something with NPM it doesn't work. I have node installed with the `version 0.10.7` and npm with `version 1.2.21`. I need to install coffee-script and it gives me this error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-39-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! cwd /home/sasuke/Videos/Node.js/Ex_Files_Node.js_FL/Exercise Files/3 Modules
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.18
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sasuke/Videos/Node.js/Ex_Files_Node.js_FL/Exercise Files/3 Modules/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've saw this link:
https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2677
But after I tried to check the proxies I got this:

```
~ > npm config get proxy
proxy-url:port
~ > npm config get https-proxy
proxy-url:port
```

Later on that post someone said to change the token at `/usr/local/etc/npmrc` But I don't have that file. After that I've update node to `v0.10.18` but I still have the same error.  I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 and I still have no idea how to fix this. Please help.

Edited question:
I've deleted the `npm proxy` and `npm https-proxy` and now coffeescript has being installed but showing some warnings

```
sudo npm install -g coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script/-/coffee-script-1.6.3.tgz
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/couch-login requires request@'~2.9.202' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.25.0
coffee-script@1.6.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
```

After I've type coffee it exists and gives me the REPL prompt. Will this keep working fine even with those warnings while installing?

Comment: What's the version of npm after updating to the latest node? Because if it's not 1.3.5 or higher, you're using the wrong version of npm (did you install it separately way back when? if so, remove that installation, as npm is now bundled with nodejs)

Comment: what's the lead up to your error, just `npm install coffeescript`?

Comment: also probably worth doing a quick search on https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues?state=open and filing it if it's not a known issue.

Comment: I've edited the question answering your question but having one more issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way.

Comment: It should work fine; you can try an `npm update -g` to forward all your globally intalled packages including the dependencies for coffee script

Answer (score 2):

The solution is here:

[Manually installing NPM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605621/manually-installing-npm-packages)

```
npm set proxy $PROXY
npm set https-proxy $PROXY
```